# WordPress Toolset - Pagination error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, pagination

My problem is simple, by I fear the sollution might not be.

I'm working on this site:
http://portugal.dk.linux134.unoeuro-server.com

It's a WordPress solution with Avada Theme and Toolset Plugins enabled. 
The only other plugins i run, are BackupBuddy and Contact Form 7.

My problem is, is that the pagination on my blog/post views suddenly stopped working. I've tried several suggestions like turning op the "max_input_vars" to 3000, in php.ini. And increasing the memory_limit to 256M.

*To see the problem "in action" try pushing the button "Indlæs flere", under the posts.*

I've worked on issues there might be with the Ajax, Jquery og the Wordpress version it self. Nothing seems to be wrong, and the problem just appeared.

I know there is a very logical explanation to this, but i'm lost in trying to find it. So does anyone out there know about WordPress and specifically the Toolset plugin, and can you help me? :)

Here is the documentation on the "view" i'm working on:

SCREENSHOTS OF THE SETTINGS: 
[image]
[image]

LOOP OUTPUT:

```
[wpv-layout-start]
    [wpv-items-found]
    <!-- wpv-loop-start -->
    <wpv-loop wrap="1" pad="true">
        [wpv-item index=1]
            <div class="col-sm-6 nth-blog-loop">
                [wpv-post-body view_template="loop-item-in-home-blog-view-after-first-two"]
            </div>
        [wpv-item index=other]
            <div class="col-sm-12">[wpv-post-body view_template="loop-item-in-home-blog-view-after-first-two"]</div>
        [wpv-item index=pad]
            <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
        [wpv-item index=pad-last]
            <div class="col-sm-12"></div>

    </wpv-loop>
    <!-- wpv-loop-end -->
    [/wpv-items-found]
    [wpv-no-items-found]
        <strong>[wpml-string context="wpv-views"]No items found[/wpml-string]</strong>
    [/wpv-no-items-found]
[wpv-layout-end]
```

TEMPLATE FOR THE VIEW

```
<article class="post-article col-sm-12">
  <a href="[wpv-post-url]">

    <div class="col-sm-12 desktop"><img src="[wpv-post-featured-image size="medium" output="url"]"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 desktop">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>[wpv-post-title]</h2>
        <p>[types field='headertekst'][/types]</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="post-info">
            <i>[wpv-post-date]</i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-12 mobile"><img src="[wpv-post-featured-image size="medium" output="url"]"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 mobile">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>[wpv-post-title]</h2>
        <p>[types field='headertekst'][/types]</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="post-info">
            <i>[wpv-post-date]</i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </a>

  <a href="[wpv-post-url]" class="read-more"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</article>
```

FILTER:

```
[wpv-layout-meta-html]
[wpv-filter-meta-html]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into your View (in Toolset). Then go to the 'pagination' area and check what it says there. It may say 'Default setting = 10'. Just change that to 10. Save it all and refresh the page. This may also help you out: https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/views-shortcodes/#wpv-items-found